# Skip layers with no data when plotting maps in R TMAP

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, try-catch, tmap

I am trying to plot maps using a loop but want the loop to plot all tm_shape variables with data and skip the components without data. Here is a sample:

```
library(tmap)
for(i in unique(NLD_muni$province)) {
tm_shape(NLD_muni[NLD_muni$province %in% i , ]) +  tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
tm_polygons(col = c("population", "pop_0_14", "pop_15_24",
                "pop_25_44")) +  tm_shape(NLD_muni) + tm_polygons("pop_men") +
tm_facets(nrow = 2, sync = TRUE)  }
```

In the example above, how can I plot the population data defined in the first tm_shape() and skip  the next tm_shape(pop_men) if the subset for pop_men is empty? My loop crashes instead of plotting the layers with data and moving on to the next i polygon in the loop.
Some of the tmap syntax is similar to ggplot2 so ideas on getting this done in ggplot2 are also welcome

Comment: A quick fix would be to use an `if-else` to check whether `pop_men` is empty. If FALSE create a map with all layers, if TRUE make a map without the layers related to `pop_men`.